# Observable<Drawable> to simple Drawable

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have Android application with method which return image as Observable. I need this image to use it in button.setDrawable(Drawable). So I need simple Drawable type. How to get image like this from this return statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I need simple Drawable type. How to get image like this from this
>   return statement?

you have to subscribe the `Observable`. The `Subscribe#onNext` will receive the `Drawable` as parameter. Be aware  that you have to call `setButton` from the Ui thread. So remember to be observing (`observeOn`) to the right thread (the UI thread).

Edit

```
drawableObservable
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Drawable>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {   
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Drawable drawable) {
        }
});
```

or with lambda

```
 drawableObservable
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe(button::setBackground, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

Comment: thank you, and one more question. If I implement it in `       `.subscribe(drawable -> radioButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, drawable, null));` image is visible only if Button is checked. I want this image to be displayed all the time.

Comment: that shouldn't be the case. Probably the issue lies everywhere else. Try to figure it out, if you can't feel free to open a new topic

Comment: what should be the datatype for Observable??

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your observable is names `obs`:

`obs.toBlocking().first()`

This will block until the Drawable is emitted by the observable.

Alternatively, use `subscribe()` to get the Drawable as soon as it's emitted by the observable, without blocking.

If you want to block until the observable is done before calling `setDrawable()`, use `toBlocking`. If you want it to happen whenever the observable finishes (as a callback), `subscribe`

Comment: It's bad form to turn Observables into blocking objects.

Comment: That's not true, it depends on the use case. There are plenty of cases in which you need to wait for a result, and then return it.